# Can I start Cannabis sativa out of edible husked seeds bought in grocery store

Tags: seeds, germination

Recently I bought in grocery store edible husked Cannabis sativa seeds 
Can I start a plant out of eadible husked seeds? If no then why?

I'm asking if a plant will actually start out of **husked** seeds, not if it's legal to grow Cannabis.

Answer (score 6):

Are you absolutely certain that the seeds you've bought are Cannabis sativa? I'd be very surprised if they are, they're much more likely to be Cannabis indica, commonly known as hemp seeds, and they are edible and relatively nutritious, like most seeds. They are also readily available in the UK in health food shops, unlike Cannabis sativa seeds. However, in law, there is no distinction between Cannabis sativa and Cannabis indica, so generally, home growing of these plants is considered illegal. You may want to check the law for the area where you live, in case there's some exception.

Cannabis indica (hemp) is commercially grown here in the UK, mostly for industrial purposes, but it would still be illegal for an individual to grow their own, even though its not actually Cannabis sativa (this last being most definitely illegal to grow, certainly in the UK).

More information in the link below regarding the differences between the two plants, particularly in relation to the content of psychoactive substances

http://www.leafscience.com/2014/09/16/5-differences-hemp-marijuana/

UPDATED ANSWER

Following your edit to your question, your seeds are obviously husked, but should also be sterilized, meaning 'cracked' which should prevent them from growing - but doesn't always. I should add that, if they were not sold as Cannabis sativa, they will definitely be Cannabis indica, hemp in other words. If you still want to bother to try to grow them, sow some and see what happens. Here's a thread from 2008 on this subject, may be of some use, not sure

https://www.uk420.com/boards/index.php?showtopic=140125

Comment: "Are you absolutely certain that the seeds you've bought are Cannabis sativa" No I'm not, this is just my guess.

Comment: Heh, you midunderstand my question, I've edited it now.

Comment: Bamboo, you got this backwards. Sativa is used as hemp, and some cultivars of sativa are used recreationally and medicinally. Indica is used pretty exclusively for recreation and medicine, but is also used for as a breeding partner with sativa to produce interesting cross breeds and cultivars. The third kind is called ruderalis which is used in north Eurasian folk medicine but has little use as hemp or recreation.

Comment: @Escoce - read the first link I provided - there's another link within it to how to tell the difference between C. sativa (marijuana) and C. indica (hemp). There are, though many sub species, some closer to marijuana, some closer to hemp in terms of THC levels, which should be under 0.3% to be classified as hemp (in some countries, though not USA, you guys don't grow either of these commercially anyway). Cannabis sativa varieties are grown here (illegally) quite frequently, and not because it makes good rope...

Comment: @Bamboo it really is backwards. The article you pointed me to also says so.

Comment: @Escoce - Okay, let's try to clear this up. I'm referring to marijuana as being C. sativa and hemp as being C. indica. The real difference in the classification in chemical terms is the level of THC compared with the level of CBN. THC is the reason people smoke marijuana, and that is C. sativa - if you want lower THC but high CBN, you'd use hemp, and this is C. indica. Link here http://medicalmarijuana.procon.org/view.answers.php?questionID=000638

Comment: @Bamboo wow I always thought marijuana is C. indica (for smoking and illegal in most countries), C. sativa is for any other purpose (and legal in most countries - under some conditions).

Comment: @MarianPaździoch, ah, well, there you go... its sativa varieties you want for the THC... and certainly, I've eaten hemp seeds (gave me indigestion actually) and I wouldn't want those full of THC, thanks, which, if they're sold in shops here, they won't be.

Comment: Husking is likely to be a traumatic process for the little seeds. Many seeds are husked by flinging them at a steel plate at ~120Kph. Steaming or boiling is also sometimes involved.

Comment: @Bamboo but bamboo, I think you are getting them mixed up. It's C Sativa that is used for hemp, and C indica that's used as a pure breed for recreation or crossed with sativa to develop some "dank bud" (excuse the expression, but that is the correct expression). The websites you cited also say what I am saying. C sativa is the one that grows upright and has strong fibers, C indica is droopy and isn't worth harvesting for hemp fibers.

Comment: @Escoce. Well, you're obviously interpreting things differently from me... but I stand by what I'm saying. Even in appearance, sativa strains are obviously marijuana, whereas hemp strains look like hemp, and I'm not going to say too much about how I know that, so we'll have to agree to disagree. People will have to make their own minds up by reading the various links, if they're interested.

Comment: @Escoce - have you gathered your info from Wiki? Because there, they say the exact opposite of the scientific analysis link I've attached in a previous comment. There is definitely a great deal of confusion about the various strains of Cannabis - all I can tell you is, C. indica is grown here in the UK, under licence, for agricultural hemp use (paper and so on), and not for medical use. Sativa cannot be grown because of increased chance of higher THC, again, the opposite of Wiki  - which is an example of why I don't trust Wikipedia and always seek a second, scientific, corroborative source...